# MS Access SQL - Count for each record in a recordset

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access

I use the query to return all of the values from one table, along with a count of votes from one table, and a count of comments from another.

I have got it to work for loading an individual record

```
DCount('[query_id]','[comments]','[query_id]=" & Target & "')
```

However if I add something similar to the query that returns every query_id, the count shows the same for them all.

Is there a different function I can use than DCount to achieve this?

My previous issue was using count, and as the query had non unique data it was counting all votes from a person (i.e if I had made 6 votes, the count would show as 6 for any record my user id was attached to).

Comment: First of all in VBA you use " double quotes  for string vars like field/table name So try `DCount("[query_id]","[comments]","[query_id]=" & Target )`

Comment: Sorry, those comments are from my Excel query, and it runs fine for the selection of an individual record (the double quotes related in syntax errors)

To clarify, the DCount I posted above is working as intended, the issue is where I don't specify a record Id (Target variable) - so I don't think DCount is appropriate.

Comment: `DCount` counts the No. of values in 1st param -field name, in table -second param. If you ommit the 3rd param you get a count of **all lines** in your table. If this is equel to the filtered case i.e  `[query_id]= 123` then DCount does not work properely for you. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/he-il/vba/access-vba/articles/application-dcount-method-access) you can learn more about this and similar VBA functions

Comment: Please [provide](http://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) sample data and expected result. If you want multiple records, you probably need GROUP BY and Count(). [How to ask a good SQL question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/3820271).

Comment: Thanks for that, you were right about both Count() and GROUP BY, and I have managed to solve the issue with sub select statements - I have added my answer in, but apologise for wording the question poorly. I will read that link you just sent me for next time. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may be after something like:

```
DCount("*","[comments]","[person_id] = " & [Target] & "")
```

where [Target] is the field holding the PersonId of the other table.

Comment: I probably didn't word my question very well, but I have actually managed to find a solution using sub SELECT statements

`(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM vote WHERE query_id = issues.query_id) AS voteCount, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comments WHERE query_id = issues.query_id) AS commentCount`

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to get the results I expected by using sub select statements in the SELECT clause

```
SELECT issues.query_id, issues.query_raised_by, issues.query_raised_date, issues.query_summary, issues.query_status, issues.query_status_date, issues.query_detail, issues.query_response
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM vote WHERE query_id = issues.query_id) AS voteCount, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comments WHERE query_id = issues.query_id) AS commentCount
```